# how to write a input statement which can take any data type as input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, user-input

Is it possible to write a input statement that can take any kind of input such as int,float on user's wish.As we cannot enter a floating number using a input statement defined for integers in python

Comment: Well, if you know that the user is going to input float then `float(raw_input())` it!

Comment: I want to make a calculator that accept the input first then do the operation,so here user can enter any data type so how can I make that heppen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just always convert to a `float` and then even if they enter an `int`, the calculations will still work out fine.